# How to keep navbar on ProductList Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am working on my `MVCOnlineShop`, i made on the homepage on the `navbar` a `dropdownlist` with categories as `dropdown` button and products as `dropdowncontent`, i want to keep this on the `ProductList` `View`:

this is my `CategoryLayout.cshtml`(**`PartialView`**):

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CategoryLayout";
}

@foreach (var Category in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">
                @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName,
"ProductList", new { Category = Category.CategoryID }, new { @style = "color:#1ABC9C;text-decoration:none;" })
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-content">
            @foreach (var Product in Category.Products)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName,
     "Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID }, new { style = "text-decoration:none;" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
}
```

this is my `ProductList.cshtml` **`PartialView`**:

```
@model MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductList";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/Productjs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Productjs/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Productcss/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/Productcss/2-col-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var Product in Model.Products)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Product.ImageID" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">@Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName, "Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID })</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is how i rendered the `CategoryLayout.cshtml` in the `_Layout.cshtml` to show the `dropdownlist` on the `homepage`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        @Html.Partial("CategoryLayout")
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

***Question:*** how to show this `navbar` on the `ProductList` too?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

Create a child action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Navbar()
{
    var categories = // get categories;
    return PartialView("_Navbar", categories);
}
```

Then, create a partial view to render the navbar (`_Navbar.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>
@foreach (var Category in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">
                @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName, "ProductList", new { Category = Category.CategoryID }, new { @style = "color:#1ABC9C;text-decoration:none;" })
            </button>

            <div class="dropdown-content">
            @foreach (var Product in Category.Products)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName, "Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID }, new { style = "text-decoration:none;" })
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

Then, call the following where you want the navbar to appear:

```
@Html.Action("Navbar", "Foo")
```

Where `"Foo"` is the name of the controller where you added the child action. Then, the view can use whatever model it needs to you and you can still render your navbar with its own model.

Comment: isn't that a bit complicated ?  I thought OP was just looking to create a layout (containing a navbar) for what appear to be likely master page

Comment: @JasonKrs: Not at all. Frankly, it's *not* complicated. This is about an easy as things can be. Second, the OP needs a model to render the navbar, which can't be done with a layout alone. Layouts cannot have their own model declarations unless every view that ever uses them will always provide that same model. In other words, not likely, and definitely doesn't work in the OP's scenario.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood I think what you are looking for is a **master page**

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) says :

> ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application.

Notice the part saying : **standard behavior that you want for all of the pages ...in your application**

So what you'll do is rethink your approach. Every element that must appear on every page is to be defined in the *master page* view.

Please read this [MSDN article about creating a master page and child pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx)

Simply, this is how your master page should be :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="you_file_name.cs" Inherits="Site" %>

<html>
    <head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <!-- some other elements like scripts, css, etc...-->
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">@Html.Partial("CategoryLayout")</ul>
    </div>
       <!-- Here add the code for rendering any other view at will ; for instance ProductList -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Becarefull though : ALL other views that you want to render inside the master page will have to be created accordingly (create view content with master page... and select the appropriate master page on view creation dialog)

Comment: This is MVC. Master pages are Web Forms. Apples and Oranges.

Comment: And point in fact, Web Forms has a somewhat parallel concept of a child action, called "controls", which is what you'd have to use in the master page scenario. In some ways, a "control", is actually more complicated than a child action.

Comment: You might want to check your smug attitude until you have a clue. MVC is backwards compatible with Web Forms, so you can do things like run an ASPX page in an MVC website. Then, with a little hackery, you can also change the template renderer from Razor to Web Forms and create some sort of Frankenstein monstrosity of the two. BUT, and it's a very big "but", This is non-standard, not-recommended, and frankly stupid. Just because I can go hopscotch in the middle of the freeway, doesn't mean I *should*.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Awww sorry friend. In no way I was trying to offend you. My sincere apologies. My comment was disproportionate and I'm sorry for that. I'm going to remove it instantly. Thanks for clarifying to me it exists because of backward compatibility.